# C++ Asynchronous creation of objects

Tags: c++, api, asynchronous, builder, chaining

I currently have an asynchronous API where a Manager class is responsible of creating other objects of class `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. The creation is asynchronous, and every call to a function `manager.createXXX()` will be accompanied by its callback `on_createXXX_done(A& a)`.

The creation of the `A`, `B`, `C` objects need to be sequential. And a typical use of the API will involve calling the creation of `A`, and in its callback, triggering the creation of `B`, and so on.

This involves having the creation logic split into many functions, which I find ugly. Furthermore, operations that need to be performed once all the objects are created will need to be coded on the callback of the last created object (`C`), even if there is no direct relation between that object and the operation to perform.

Builder design pattern does not actually fit since manager does not own the objects `A`, `B`, `C`, it just helps on the creation and return them.

```
void on_creationA_done(A& a)
{
    m_a = a;
    //Trigger next creation
    m_manager.createB()
}
void on_creationB_done(B& b)
{
    m_b = b;
    //Trigger next creation
    m_manager.createC()
}

void on_creationC_done(C& c)
{
    m_c = c;
    //No more creations are needed. Just perform some post-creation actions  
    do_something() // This needs to be called once all A, B, C are created.
}
```

I have also checked folly/futures to chain asynchronous operations but that would involved exposing folly library through our public API, right?

What would be a good pattern to use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit restrictive (and not extensible) to chain the A,B,C creations inside their callbacks. If more use cases need to be implemented in future, you will have to handle them inside the callbacks too, making the code too complex and not intuitive.

The current case is a specific use case which should be dealt with the aid of another manager class, let's call it UseCaseABC, which knows about the use case's specific requirements, constraints etc.

In UseCaseABC class you could keep track of A,B,C objects' creation and call do_something whenever all three objects exist.

```
class UseCaseABC
{

    void on_creationA_done(A& a) 
    {
       m_A = a;
       NotifyCreation();
    }
    void on_creationB_done(B& b) 
    {
       m_B = b;
       NotifyCreation();
    }
    void on_creationC_done(C& c) 
    {
       m_C = c;
       NotifyCreation();
    }    

    void NotifyCreation()
    {
       if (all three objects created)
       {
           do_something();

           ClearABCMembers();
       }
    }
}
```

If A,B,C objects' creation is triggered asynchronously by many clients, you could replace m_A,m_B,m_C instances by object pools accessed in a thread safe way.

Comment: I do not quite agree with the solution. The manager class can create more objects (or less). Let's say you have objects from A - Z. Each use case or scenario could request the creation of any subset of objects. That makes your solution impossible since you would need to create a UseCase class per subset, so N subsets (being N = pow(2, number of objects in the set))

Comment: It's up to you to decide if you must create separate use case classes or a general one to handle all cases. And that depends on the complexity of each use case and the number of them.